Get historical balance of ETH and ERC-20 Tokens
Now I am wondering how to get the historical balance of ETH and ERC-20 Tokens, like the web tool provided by etherscan. I attempted to add all the transactions on Etherscan to get the historical ERC-20 balances but some of the balances are less than zero which is impossible.
For example, considering address 0x3CC3AE64f26C8FA893358E5AE7717a0D001C0940 and token contract (Aura) 0xC0c293ce456fF0ED870ADd98a0828Dd4d2903DBF, this address received 1,014.571495152404966172 Aura on May-01-2023 as shown by tx 0xe5213a18e203f51f76f36f86a0c63eb7b69867eee80e29b0c577073ee1f1e6d3. However, the web tool shows that on May-03-2023 is zero but on May-02-2023 is 1,014.571495152404966172. But I haven't found any tx that pays 1,014.571495152404966172 Aura on May-02-2023 or May-03-2023. So I am wondering why the web tool shows that on May-03-2023 is zero.
I appreciate your answers and help!

I can find out the transaction which transfered 1,014 AURA on MAY-02-2023.
This is tx: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x177633fbfa3481b1077941dd9b3466bd7174b60976fb9f3e5d9e14eb4870df73

He transferred those aura to CoW Protocol. It means the tool is not wrong, you can look for transactions of ERC20 transfer by accessing this tab https://etherscan.io/tokentxns?a=0x3CC3AE64f26C8FA893358E5AE7717a0D001C0940&p=8

I appreciate your answer. You really help me a lot! The https://etherscan.io/tokentxns?a=0x3CC3AE64f26C8FA893358E5AE7717a0D001C0940&p=8 only shows the latest 5000 transactions. Are there any ways I can find all the ERC20 transfer? I found the 'CSV export' tool https://etherscan.io/exportData?type=addresstokentxns&a=0x683a42e5b414ae5cf79ece7e369ca5937fdcdc11, but it is a form and I would like a website layout like the tab your provided https://etherscan.io/tokentxns?a=0x3CC3AE64f26C8FA893358E5AE7717a0D001C0940&p=8.
I appreciate your assistance!

You may need to search another 3rd party to support it. It requires a lot of resources to scan, so I don't think it will be free. I haven't try that  stuff before so I can't give you any suggestion

Thanks for your reply! I will try another 3rd party.

Please accept the answer if it solves your problem
